# Agrupar filas de forma parcial

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

Muy buenos días a tod@s.

Tengo los siguientes datos:

```
import pandas as pd

datos = {
'estados': [-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1],       # estados: -1, 0, 1
'valores': [34, 29, 28, 30, 35, 33, 33, 36, 40, 41]  # valores: <float>
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=datos)

print(df)

>>> 
   estados  valores
0       -1       34
1       -1       29
2       -1       28
3        1       30
4        1       35
5       -1       33
6        0       33
7        1       36
8        1       40
9        1       41
```

Necesito agrupar los datos **usando PANDAS** (y/o funciones de orden superior) (*ya realice el ejercicio usando ciclos for*), necesito agrupar los datos teniendo como guía la columna «estados». Pero la agrupación no debe ser de todos los datos, solamente necesito agrupar los datos que son aledaños... de la siguiente manera:

DataFrame inicial:

```
   estados  valores
0       -1       34 ┐
1       -1       29 │    Agrupa esta parte (estados = -1)
2       -1       28 ┘
3        1       30 ┐    Agrupa esta parte (estados =  1)
4        1       35 ┘
5       -1       33     'Agrupa' esta parte (estados = -1)
6        0       33     'Agrupa' esta parte (estados =  0)
7        1       36 ┐
8        1       40 │    Agrupa esta parte (estados =  1)
9        1       41 ┘
```

Tendría como resultado un DataFrame, con una agrupación por segmentos (de la columna «estados») y en otra columna la suma de los datos (de la columna «valores»)

DataFrame esperado:

```
   estados  valores
0       -1       91     (valores=34+29+28)
1        1       65     (valores=30+35)
2       -1       33
3        0       33
4        1       117    (valores=36+40+41)
```

Vosotros que sois mas versados en estos temas, quizá me puedan ayudar a realizar esta operación.

¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

datos = {
   'estados': [-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1],       
   'valores': [34, 29, 28, 30, 35, 33, 33, 36, 40, 41] 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=datos)
```

El objetivo esta en identificar los valores consecutivos. Se compara el valor de `'estados'` con este mismo en su valor periódico, con la función `shift()`.

Cada vez que la condición es verdadera (empieza un valor diferente en `'estados'`) se incrementa un valor con la función `cumsum()`. Este valor se mantendra hasta que el valor cambie.

```
df['consecutive'] = (df['estados'] != df['estados'].shift()).cumsum()

print(df.groupby(['consecutive']).agg({
    "estados": "first",
    "valores": "sum"
}).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Comment: Emanuek muchas gracias, tu solución es ¡muy elegante!.